# Xcode Directory not found for option '-L"/Users/

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I'm getting these erors,

[image]

Project building successfully, But when I'm integrating a static library its giving me that error.

Can anyone help me to solve this

Thanks

Comment: "directory not found" is simply a warning, the real error is a missing library of `pj-arm-apple-darwin9`.  What is that?

Comment: "pj-arm-apple-darwin9" is a library exist's in project resources.